# ReactJS - Pre-Populating a Dynamic Field in Update Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am currently working on an update form (put request) on ReactJS. I have the form data stored as this.state that I want to use to prepopulate, however, I am not sure how to implement it into the dynamic field, as I would want the prepopulated data to still hold on to the 'remove' function to remove that row of fields from the form. Also, I would want the rows to be rendered automatically when the form is rendered. Meaning, if there are two rows of the dynamic field, those two rows has to be shown without pressing the 'add' button. Below is the snippet of the code and a screenshot of the form.

```
<Form.List name={addon.model} key={addon.model}>
    {(fields, { add, remove }) => {
        return (
            <div>
                {fields.map((field, index) => (
                    <Row key={field.key}>
                         {addon.fields.map((a) => (
                              <Col key={'c' + a.key}>
                                  <Input placeholder={a.label} name={a.key} key={'i' + a.key} 
                                   onChange={(e) => this.onChangeAddOn(e, index, addon.model)} />
                               </Col>
                          ))}
                          <Col flex="none">
                               <MinusCircleOutlined
                                className="dynamic-delete-button"
                                onClick={() => {
                                    remove(field.name);
                                    }}
                                />
                          </Col>
                      </Row>
                   ))
                   }
                   <Button
                      type="dashed"
                      onClick={() => {
                           add();
                      }}
                      style={{ width: "100%" }}
                   >
                      <PlusOutlined /> Add POCs
                   </Button>
                   </div>
                );
           }}
</Form.List>
```

screenshot (the '-' button is the remove button, and i am free to add more fields if i press the 'Add POC' button, but the main point is that the two rows of data must be rendered at the start together with the form => data stored in this.state)
[image]

All help is appreciated and welcomed, please do help to point me in the right direction as I am still new to ReactJS! I did take a look at render props and Form.List, but I am not sure how to implement it still.

Comment: Why don't you set `fields` in ComponentDidMount with the fetched data?

Comment: oh i did not think of that, how do i do that? and if i were to set the fields in ComponentDidMount, would it also have the functionality of the 'remove' button?